# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor;

Tags: android, maven, android-library

I have an aar library project, I am using it in a sample project. I added the relevant library to Maven Local Repository. When I check the Pom file, I can see it as Okhttp3 / logging / HttpLoggingInterceptor dependency. But i am facing with below screen shoot error. Any suggestions?

[image]

my parent app gradle file looks like above code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deneme"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.6'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.mylibrary:feature:1.0.15@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is that when the pom file is generated it generates incorrectly, I am actually having a problem on the wrong sub-mobule. After I fixed my pom settings my problem was resolved.